# How can I compile a CUDA program for sm_1X AND sm_2X when I have a surface declaration

Tags: c++, cuda, macros, c-preprocessor, nvcc

I am writing a library that uses a surface (to re-sample and write to a texture) for a performance gain:

```
...
surface<void,  2> my_surf2D; //allows writing to a texture
...
```

The target platform GPU has compute capability 2.0 and I can compile my code with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 ...
```

and it works just fine.

The problem is when I am trying to develop and debug the library on my laptop which has an NVIDIA ION GPU with compute capability 1.1 (I would also like my library to be backwards compatible). I know this architecture does not support surfaces so I used the nvcc macros in my device code to define an alternate code path for this older architecture:

```
#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#warning using kernel for CUDA ARCH < 2.0
...
temp_array[...] =  tex3D(my_tex,X,Y,Z+0.5f);
#else
...
surf2Dwrite( tex3D(my_tex,X,Y,Z+0.5f), my_surf2D, ix*4, iy,cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
#endif
```

The problem is that when I do:

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11
```

I get this error:

```
ptxas PTX/myLibrary.ptx, line 1784; fatal  : Parsing error near '.surf': syntax error
```

When I look at the PTX file is see what appears to be the surface declaration:

```
.surf .u32 _ZN16LIB_15my_surf2DE;
```

If I try to put a similar macro around the surface declaration in my source code:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 200
#warning skipping surface declaration for nvcc trajectory
#else
surface ...
#endif
#else
#warning keeping surface declaration by default
surface ...
#endif
```

I get an error saying the surface variable is undefined in the host code call to to bind cuda surface to array. Should I **add the macro around the bind function** as well?

I'm not sure if it is possible, or if I goofed somewhere, please help.

Comment: Are you using preprocessor "protection" around the declaration of the surfaces as well as the access calls inside device code?

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds like it should work just fine. Which variable is undefined in your error?

Comment: I will update my post with more details about how I tried to wrap surface declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this thread should show up as answered...

I got it to work (quite simple actually). You must put a macro around **all three** possible places where the surface reference is used, and be careful to use the macros properly (it turns out, __CUDACC__ is not necessary).

**The following only changes the code when compiling for compute capability < 2.0**

The surface declaration:

```
//enable backwards compatability:
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) & (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#warning skipping surface declarations for compute capability < 2.0
#else
surface<void,  2> my_surf2D; //allows writing to a texture
#endif
```

Surface binding:

```
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) & (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#warning skipping cudaBindSurfaceToArray for compute capability < 2.0
...
#else
errorCode = cudaBindSurfaceToArray(my_surf2D, my_cudaArray2D);
#endif
```

And Surface writing:

```
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) & (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#warning using kernel for compute capability < 2.0
...
temp_array[...] =  tex3D(my_tex,X,Y,Z+0.5f);
#else
...
surf2Dwrite( tex3D(my_tex,X,Y,Z+0.5f), my_surf2D, ix*4, iy,cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
#endif
```

This works for both virtual and real targets (-arch=compute_XX and -arch=sm_XX respectively).

Thanks to [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) and [Roger Dahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442006/roger-dahl) for pointing me in the right direction, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809924/1297040) from [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) which has a great explanation of nvcc/CUDA macros as well.

Comment: What is weird to me is that both the surface definition and the surface binding is really host code, and in theory `__CUDA_ARCH__` is not defined in host code. But if it works, it works.