# write a cuda program to compile both sm_1x and sm_2x

Tags: cuda

My problem is very similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161387/how-can-i-compile-a-cuda-program-for-sm-1x-and-sm-2x-when-i-have-a-surface-decla), but I am not able to fix it.

I have a CUDA program using cuda layered texture. This feature is only available with Fermi architecture (with compute capability more than or equal to 2.0). If the GPU is not Fermi, I use 3d texture as substitution for layered texture. I use __CUDA_ARCH__ in my code when declaring the texture reference (texture reference needs to be global) as this:

```
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200
    texture<float, cudaTextureType2DLayered> depthmapsTex;
#else
    texture<float, cudaTextureType3D> depthmapsTex;
#endif
```

The problem I have is that it seems __CUDA_ARCH__ is not defined.

The things I have tried:

1) __CUDA_ARCH__ is able to work correctly within cuda kernel. I know from the NVCC document that __CUDA_ARCH__ is not able to work correctly within host code. I have to define the texture reference as global variable. Does it belong to host code? The extension of the file being compiled is .cu.

2) I have a program that works correctly using layered texture. Then I add __CUDA_ARCH__ macro in two ways:

```
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    texture<float, cudaTextureType2DLayered> depthmapsTex; 
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    texture<float, cudaTextureType2DLayered> depthmapsTex; 
#endif
```

I found neither of them work. Both have the same error. **error : identifier "depthmapsTex" is undefined**. It looks as if the MACRO __CUDA_ARCH__ is defined and not defined at the same time. I suspect this relates to the fact that the compilation has two stages, and only one of the stage can see __CUDA_ARCH__, but I am not sure what has happened exactly.

I use cmake + visual studio 10 to set up the project and compile the code. I suspect if there is anything wrong here.

I am not sure if I have provided enough information. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**
I tried to find any example that uses __CUDA_ARCH__ in Nvidia CUDA SDK 5.0. The following code is extracted from line 20 to line 24 in  file GPUHistogram.h in the project grabcutNPP.

```
#if __CUDA_ARCH__<300
#define PARALLEL_HISTS 64
#else
#define PARALLEL_HISTS 8
#endif
```

And from line 216 to line 219, it uses the MACRO PARALLEL_HISTS:

```
int gpuHistogramTempSize(int n_bins)
{
    return n_bins * PARALLEL_HISTS * sizeof(int);
}
```

But I found there is a problem here. PARALLEL_HISTS is not correctly defined. If I change the first clause to **#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)&& __CUDA_ARCH__<300**, I found the **CUDA_ARCH** is not defined. Does the CUDA SDK example use **CUDA_ARCH** in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the exact problem which may well have an elegant solution. Here is an inelegant  brute-force approach I have used in the past. Create two kernels with identical signatures, but different names (e.g. foo_sm10(), foo_sm20(), in two separate .cu files. Compile one file for sm_10, and the other file for sm_20. Move common code that is independent of compute capability into a header file, and include it from both of the previously mentioned .cu files. In the host code, create a function pointer to invoke the architecture-dependent kernels. Initialize the function pointer to the approriate architecture-dependent kernel based on the compute capability detected at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to figure out the compute capability of your GPU, you could try something like:

```
int devID;    
cudaDeviceProp props;
CUDA_SAFE_CALL( cudaGetDevice(&devID) );
CUDA_SAFE_CALL( cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, devID) );

float cc;
cc = props.major+props.minor*0.1;
printf("\n:: CC: %.1f",cc);
```

But I have no idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: I know this, but I need to know the GPU compute capability during the compile time